# char array to LPCTSTR conversion in c

Tags: c, windows, arrays, char

Does anyone know how to convert a char array to a LPCTSTR in c?

Edit:

For more reference, I need to add an integer to a string then convert that string to LPCTSTR for the first parameter of the windows function CreateFile().

This is the hardcoded example which I am currently using, but I need to be able to pass in any number to use as a port number.

```
CreateFile(_T("\\\\.\\COM11")... //hardcoded for com port 11
```

and here are several things I have tried, which I believe include the following suggestions for the next 2 answers of this post. They don't work unfortunately. If anyone could point out something I've done wrong and could possibly solve my problem, I'd appreciate it.

All of these examples assume that portNum is an int that is already assigned a valid value

## 1

```
char portName[12] = { 0 };

sprintf_s( portName, sizeof( portName ), "\\\\.\\COM%i", portNum );

CreateFile(portName...
```

I've also tried #1 with a LPCSTR case for what it's worth...

## 2

```
LPCSTR SomeFunction(LPCSTR aString) {
    return aString;
}

main() {

char portName[12] = { 0 };
sprintf_s( portName, sizeof( portName ), "\\\\.\\COM%i", portNum );

LPCSTR lpPortName = SomeFunction(portName);

CreateFile(lpPortName...
```

## 3

```
const char * portName = "";
sprintf_s( portName, sizeof( portName ), "\\\\.\\COM%i", portNum );

LPCSTR lpPortName = portName;

CreateFile(lpPortName...
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can implicitly convert a char array to an `LPCSTR` without any casts:

```
void SomeFunction(LPCSTR aString);
...
char myArray[] = "hello, world!";
SomeFunction(myArray);
```

An `LPCSTR` is a Windows typedef for a long pointer to a constant string.  Back in the dark days of Win16 programming, there were different types of pointers: *near* pointers and *far* pointers, sometimes also known as *short* and *long* pointers respectively.  Near pointers could only point to a 64KB segment of memory determined by one of the x86 segment registers.  Far pointers could point to anything.  Nowadays in Win32 with virtual memory, there is no need for near pointers -- all pointers are long.

So, an `LPSTR` is a typedef for a `char *`, or pointer to a string.  An `LPCSTR` is the `const` version, i.e. it is a typedef for a `const char *`.  In C, arrays decay into pointers to their first elements, so a `char[]` decays into a `char*`.  Finally, any type of "pointer to T" (for any type T) can be implicitly converted into a "pointer to const T".  Thus, combining these three facts, we see that we can implicitly convert a `char[]` into an `LPCSTR`.

---

In response to your edit, I'm going to guess that you're compiling a Unicode application.  If you look carefully at the [documentation for `CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx), you'll notice that the filename parameter is actually an `LPCTSTR`, not an `LPCSTR` (note the `T`).

For pretty much every Win32 function that takes an argument of some string type (perhaps indirectly, i.e. as a member of a structure passed as a parameter), there are actually two versions of that function: one which takes 8-bit ANSI strings, and one which takes 16-bit wide-character strings.  To get the actual function names, you append an `A` or a `W` to the function name.  So, the ANSI version of `CreateFile()` is named `CreateFileA()`, and the wide-character version is named `CreateFileW()`.  Depending on whether or not you're compiling with Unicode enabled (i.e. whether the preprocessor symbol `_UNICODE` is defined), the symbol `CreateFile` is `#define`d to either `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW` as appropriate, and likewise for every other function that has an ANSI and a wide-character version.

Along the same lines, the type `TCHAR` is `typedef`ed to either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on whether Unicode is enabled, and `LPCTSTR` is `typedef`ed to a pointer to a `const TCHAR`.

Thus, to make your code correct, you should replace the strings you're using with `TCHAR` strings, and use the type-generic version of `sprintf_s`, `_stprintf_s`:

```
TCHAR portName[32];
_stprintf_s(portName, sizeof(portName)/sizeof(TCHAR), _T("\\\\.\\COM%d"), portNum);
CreateFile(portName, ...);
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly use the ANSI or wide-character versions of everything:

```
// Use ANSI
char portName[32];
sprintf_s(portName, sizeof(portName), "\\\\.\\COM%d", portNum);
CreateFileA(portName, ...);

// Use wide-characters
wchar_t portName[32];
swprintf_s(portName, sizeof(portName)/sizeof(wchar_t), L"\\\\.\\COM%d", portNum);
CreateFileW(portName, ...);
```

Comment: This unfortunately hasn't solved my problem, though I added a code example of what I need done--you can view the code above.

Comment: @Schyler
You don't seem to have CreateFileA() (note the 'A') in your code. Change CreateFile() to this and it should work.

Comment: Conversion to LPCSTR or LPCTSTR? Because LPCTSTR can be wchar_t* if UNICODE symbol is defined.

Comment: This answer is really helpful for someone who is starting Windows programming like myself

Answer (score 3):

In what format is your char array?

Is it a `const char[]` or a non-const?

LPCSTR is just the (somewhat) confusing Microsoft name for "Long Pointer to Constant String".

```
LPCSTR bar = "hello";
const char *foo = bar;

const char *evil = "hello";
LPCSTR sauron = evil;
```

If you need to get a non-const version, you either cast away the constness, or you copy to a new array. I would probably prefer the latter. Variables are often const for a reason, and changing them is almost always bad practice.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to explicitly put the null character at the end of the string.  The compiler should do that for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks Herms, it is correct. In fact I don't even do that in my own code. Fixed now.

Comment: Care to tell us why Foredecker, except the \0 on the end? Just saying "this is not good" without no explanation is not constructive.

Comment: The only bad thing I can think of is that it makes the strings take more memory than they need to, as the compiler will stick a null character at the end.

Comment: It is nonconstant--view the edit above of how I tried to use your example and failed.

Answer (score 2):

try like this.........

```
TCHAR *pcCommPort = TEXT("COM1");
HANDLE h = CreateFile(pcCommPort,other arguments);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char* filename;
LPCTSTR ime = CA2W(filename);
```

This is String Conversion Macro and works on my VS12

Answer (score 1):

You have string functions for TCHAR. You can use, for example, stprintf_s accepting TCHAR. This way, you make the code "independent" of unicode or multi-byte character set.

Your code (variant 1) becomes:

```
TCHAR portName[12] = { 0 };

stprintf_s( portName, sizeof( portName ) / sizeof(TCHAR), _T("\\\\.\\COM%i"), portNum );

CreateFile(portName...
```

Comment: "sizeof( portName )," -- Oops. Your answer almost taught the poster how to use TCHARs, but one buffer overflow can ruin your whole day.

Comment: sizeof( portName ) / sizeof( TCHAR )

Answer (score 0):

"Does anyone know how to convert a char array to a LPCSTR in c?"

You don't have to do anything at all. It automatically converts to that type (except in initializers and sizeof).

"CreateFile(portName..."

Perhaps you should tell us the error message that VC++ gives you at compile time?

Perhaps you should also tell us what error message VC++ gave you when Adam Rosenfield's whcar_t version didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you figured something out in the end but I had the same problem and following worked well for me:

```
int  comPortNum = 5;
char comPortName[32];
sprintf((LPTSTR)comPortName, TEXT("\\\\.\\COM%d"), comPortNum);
HANDLE h = CreateFile(comPortName,other arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old classical question. I use it in UNICODE.

```
char *pChar = "My Caption of My application";
    WCHAR wsz[512];
    swprintf(wsz, L"%S", pChar);
    SetWindowText(hWnd,         // ウィンドウまたはコントロールのハンドル
        wsz   // タイトルまたはテキスト
    );
```