# How to convert a character array to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [char array to LPCTSTR conversion in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976568/char-array-to-lpctstr-conversion-in-c)
>   [how can convert LPCSTR string into LPCTSTR string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642494/how-can-convert-lpcstr-string-into-lpctstr-string)

There is lot of material available already but I am new to C++ so I couldn't understand them properly. Please help.

Comment: If `UNICODE` is not defined, then `const char *` is the same thing as `LPCTSTR`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: But that would be a bad idea.

Comment: If you atleast bothered to search, you'd find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976568/char-array-to-lpctstr-conversion-in-c)

Comment: I have searched every where but as I am new to this i couldn't get them properly. It was last option to ask here but things are same. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

google gave me [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc), with a lot of information.

The type-name LPCTSTR can be classified as:

```
LP - Pointer
C - Constant
T = TCHAR
STR = String
```

Depending on the project settings, LPCTSTR would be mapped to either LPCSTR (ANSI) or LPCWSTR (Unicode).

The type-name LPCSTR can be classified as:

```
LP - Pointer
C - Constant
STR = String
```

A STR is the same as a char*

The type-name LPCWSTR can be classified as:

```
LP - Pointer
C - Constant
WSTR - Wide character String
```

here a WSTR is a wchar_t* or a wide char (2 byte char)

And last but not least [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138813) on how to do the conversion. As you can see there is a bit more to it that a simple type conversion.

Comment: LPCTSTR isn't another name for a `const char*`. It's a name for `const char*` or `const wchar_t*` (or even 'const unsigned short*`) depending on your compilation options.

Comment: Please elaborate when you downvote

Comment: -1 doesn't actually explain how to convert `const char *` to `LPCTSTR`, and the tone sounds rather grumpy for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks Minion91 for explaination. By saying LPCTSTR is another name for a const char * do you mean, i can do this
char abc[];
LPCTSTR xyz = abc;

Comment: The first post was actually a bit faulty, this update one should provide you with everything you need